# Bootstrap subtheme does not apply to main menu

Tags: 7, theming

After adding the "html.tpl.php" and "page.tpl.html" to my bootstrap subtheme the layout of my main menu disappeard as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image: menu]

As you can see; no bootstrap classes are applied to the menu:

```
<h2 class="block-title">Main menu</h2>
    <div class="contextual-links-wrapper"><ul class="contextual-links"><li class="menu-list first"><a href="/drupal/admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu/list?destination=node">List links</a></li>
<li class="menu-edit"><a href="/drupal/admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu/edit?destination=node">Edit menu</a></li>
<li class="block-configure last"><a href="/drupal/admin/structure/block/manage/system/main-menu/configure?destination=node">Configure block</a></li>
</ul></div>
  <ul class="menu nav"><li class="first leaf"><a href="/drupal/lessenrooster">Lessenrooster</a></li>
<li class="collapsed"><a href="/drupal/over-ons">Over ons</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/drupal/contact" title="">Contact</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a href="/drupal/fotogallerij">Fotogallerij</a></li>
</ul>
</section>
```

The bootstrap subtheme however is active:

[image]

**EDIT 1**

I indeed did use the wrong .tpl files. I now have copied the correct files to the subtheme (which included the correct .info file). However the .info file does not include the main_menu region.

```
regions[navigation]     = 'Navigation'
regions[header]         = 'Top Bar'
regions[highlighted]    = 'Highlighted'
regions[help]           = 'Help'
regions[content]        = 'Content'
regions[sidebar_first]  = 'Primary'
regions[sidebar_second] = 'Secondary'
regions[footer]         = 'Footer'
regions[page_top]       = 'Page top'
regions[page_bottom]    = 'Page bottom'
```

After clearing the cache, the main menu did not change.

**EDIT 2**

I started all over again following [this guide](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208932/how-to-keep-my-bootstrap-sub-theme-without-using-the-cdn), but still the main menu looks like crap... and if i copy over the `menu` folder from bootstrap I get an `HTTP ERROR 500` error

Comment: Where did you get your templates? Did you take your templates from the main bootstrap theme templates folder or take system templates?

Comment: your menu will be displaying under "Navigation"(region).

Answer (score 1):

You must use the template files from bootstrap theme since all those are overridden there. the templates file you should use are under `themes > bootstrap > templates > system`.

copy the page.tpl.php and html.tpl.php from there to your sub-theme.

simply use the same .info file for your sub theme as well. it will give you all the regions. set `"base theme=bootstrap"` in template_name.info file.

remember to clear the cache

Comment: Thanks. I am now using the correct .tpl files and it did change the layout of the site for the better, but the main menu did not change.

Comment: If I enable the "base bootstrap" theme the main menu looks fine.

Comment: Ok David. for the subtheme.info file you should use 
`name = subtheme_Bootstrap
description = subtheme created from bootstrap theme.
core = 7.x
base theme=bootstrap

stylesheets[all][] = 'css/style.css' /*your custom style sheet*/


version = "7.x-0.1"
core = "7.x"
project = "subtheme_bootstrap"`
and just have the page.tpl.php and html.tpl.php under your 'subtheme>templates' folder.

Comment: In your subtheme folder, you should only have `subtheme.info file` with the given content above. A `CSS folder` with custom sytlesheet (if you have one),
`templates folder` which is containing the bootstrap page.tpl.php and html.tpl.php files.